# Convert multiple character columns into numeric in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
ks3score ks4score ethnic gender SECshort
28.54   214.00  Indian  Male    Intermediate    
39.84   543.00  Indian  Male    Intermediate    
28.34   294.00  Mixed heritage  Male    Intermediate    
35.78   348.00  Mixed heritage  Male    Intermediate    
35.79   388.00  Mixed heritage  Male    Intermediate    
24.67   504.00  Pakistani   Male    Intermediate    
20.39   70.25   White British   Male    Intermediate    
27.25   92.00   White British   Male    Intermediate    
19.61   104.00  White British   Male    Intermediate    
19.61   150.00  White British   Male    Intermediate
```

I want to convert character variables into numeric variables, I have used with the code below but it convert them to `NA`.

```
cols <- c("ethnic", "gender", "SECshort")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], factor)
df[, cols]<-lapply(cols, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(df[,x])))
```

Out:

```
ks3score ks4score ethnic gender SECshort
28.54   214.00  NA  NA  NA
39.84   543.00  NA  NA  NA
28.34   294.00  NA  NA  NA
35.78   348.00  NA  NA  NA
35.79   388.00  NA  NA  NA
24.67   504.00  NA  NA  NA
20.39   70.25   NA  NA  NA
27.25   92.00   NA  NA  NA
19.61   104.00  NA  NA  NA
19.61   150.00  NA  NA  NA
```

Just wonders why I get this error? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I need fit a logistic regression model, so i think it's necesary to convert them into numeric.

Comment: It is necessary to dummy code them, which is different than converting them to numbers. Most R modeling functions (like `glm`) do this automatically, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you were trying to do :

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.integer(factor(x)))
```

You can also use :

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) match(x, unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the possibility to use `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,cols := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = cols]
```

You update by reference your subset of data (meaning of `.SD`) by applying `as.numeric` function

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
         mutate_at(vars(cols), as.integer)
```

Or with `across`

```
df <- df %>%
        mutate(across(cols, as.integer))
```